# Entity framework group by with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query

```
var maListe = (from p in db.exclure
               where (p.type.Contains("Object"))
               group p by p.libelle into g
               select new
               {
                    libellex = g.Key
               }).ToList();
```

I need to make conditions on which element to group by for example

```
if(x==0) group by p.libelle
else if (x==1) group by p.name
else  group by p.adresse
```

Is there a way to do it properly Inside my linq query ?

Comment: Where do the variables of your condition come from ? Is x known outside of the context of the query ?

Comment: Yes it's ouside my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming x is set already, try this:

```
var maListe = (from p in db.exclure
                where (p.type.Contains("Object"))
                group p by new {obj = x==0 ? p.libelle : x==1 ? p.name : p.adresse } into g
                select new
                {
                    libellex = g.Key
                }).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:**
The sort condition needs a property name to avoid the error `Invalid anonymous type member declarator.` So I've amended the line `group p by new {obj = x==0 ? p.libelle :.... etc`

Comment: well my  real variable is "groupx" instead of x, i tried your suggestion                           group p by new { groupx.Contains("objet")? p.mc_object : groupx.Contains("host") ?p.mc_host : p.mc_host_class } into g , they told me that i can't use anonymous type

Comment: anonymous invalid type member declaration

Comment: Try giving the sort property a name, like `group p by new {obj =  x==0 ...`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could create a lambda expression to be used as key selector in your group by:

```
int x=1;
Func<Exclure,object> func = (b) =>
{
   switch (x)
   {
     case  0:
       return b.libelle;
     case  1:
       return b.name;
     default:
       return b.adresse;
   }
};
var maListe = db.exclure.Where(p=>p.type.Contains("Object")).GroupBy(func).Select(g=>g.Key).ToList();
```